# __LINE__ where the function was called

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void _debug(const string& text, int line)
{
    cout << text << " " << line << endl;

}

#define _DEBUG(text) _debug(text, __LINE__);

void func1()
{
    _DEBUG("func1") // line 15
}

void func2()
{
    _DEBUG("func2") // line 20
}

int main()
{
    func1(); // line 25
    func2(); // line 26
    func1(); // line 27
    func2(); // line 28
}
```

The code above prints

```
func1 15
func2 20
func1 15
func2 20
```

Instead, I want

```
func1 25
func2 26
func1 27
func2 28
```

Is there a `macro` similar to `__LINE__` which gives me the line where the function was called?

Comment: Use `std::source_location` instead.

Comment: But you can pase it as function argument. Say `void func(int line)` and call it as `func(__LINE__);`

Comment: You can use `std::source_location` only if you can use C++20 standard and your compiler supports it. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20#C.2B.2B14_library_features

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) (since C++20), you might do (without MACRO):

```
void func1(std::source_location loc = std::source_location::current())
{
    _debug("func1", loc.line());
}

void func2(std::source_location loc = std::source_location::current())
{
    _debug("func2", loc.line());
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5aYqzbzb5)

Comment: worth noting this requires C++20 standard and proper version of compiler (for example clang still do not fully supports it): [See table of C++20 features](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20#C.2B.2B14_library_features).

Comment: Well, here on macOS I can't replicate the Demo with C++20. It behaves like `__LINE__`, guess I don't have the proper version of the compiler.

Comment: @KcFnMi The latest version of Apple's Clang supports C++20. It supported C++20 since many months ago

Comment: @Asesh can you replicate the Demo on macOS? https://developer.apple.com/xcode/cpp/ it seems source_location is there, since I can #include <source_location> but the implementation is still partial? I see it does work here on Debian 12 though.

Comment: Just tried it on macOS. It doesn't print the location of where `func1 ` was called from but the line where it's definition exists

Answer (score 0):

I just use this macro:

```c
#define QUOTE_MACRO(S_) QUOTE(S_)
#define QUOTE(S_) #S_
#define CODE_LOCATION "(" __FILE__ ":" QUOTE_MACRO(__LINE__) ")"
```

Then, I pass that into functions that may fail as a `const char*`:

```c
int might_fail(int, int, int, const char*);
// ...
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // ...
    might_fail(x, y, z, CODE_LOCATION);
}
```